# Change text in modal window depening on button clicked

Tags: jquery, html, .net

I am using jQuery Popup Overlay http://vast-eng.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/ for a modal form. What i want to achieve is change the heading of the modal depending on which open modal button is clicked.

My html looks something like this:

```
<a class="Modal_Open">Use this text as modal heading 1</a>
<a class="Modal_Open">Use this text as modal heading 2</a>

Modal:

<div id="Modal" display:none>
<p>Want to switch the text here</p>
<input type="text" />
</div>
```

My jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Modal').popup();
});
```

This is a .net project so if the solution would be easier in C# no worries.

Comment: It looks like the library is bugged. Wrong element is passed to callback `beforeopen`. Otherwise this `$('#Modal').popup({
  beforeopen: function(clickedButton) {
    $('#Modal > p:first-child').html('new: ' + clickedButton.text());
  }
});` would work.

Answer (score 0):

i have this very dirty patch solution for your situation.

if you have only `p tag` within your modal or else you use selector for `p tag`

then you can use

```
$('#Modal>p').html('Use this text as modal heading 2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Plugin has bug it seems. Else the snippets  below would work:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.Modal_Open').click(function () {
            var _title = $(this).text();
            $('#Modal').popup({
                'autoopen': true,
                'onopen': function () {
                    console.log(_title);
                    $('#Modal > p').text(_title);
                }
            });
        });
```

});

onopen method doesnt envoke. before open also does not change the passed element.

Answer (score 0):

@shekhardesigner is right. The bug in the plugin has been fixed. Here's a working example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Modal_Open').click(function () {
        var _title = $(this).text();
        $('#Modal').popup({
            'autoopen': true,
            'onopen': function () {
                console.log(_title);
                $('#Modal > p').text(_title);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EC8WP/2/